# WooCommerce or Stripe webhook for triggering shipping?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I’m selling ditigal goods and I am wondering how to trigger the delivery once the payment has been validated on my Store.

**Option 1 : Get webhook from stripe**
First option would be to create stripe webhooks and proceed to sending my products once payment has gone through.

But does Stripe have the info of what products have been bought by customer, apart from amount paid?

**Option 2: Get webhook from Woocommerce**
Second option is that Woocommerce get the info from stripe, then create a webhook there so that I sell the right goods since Woocommerce may have all the infos.

Any ideas of what webhook to create?

Comment: Definitely use a custom WooCommerce webhook. You might want to add a payment processor, or switch payment processors. If you use a stripe.com webhook, you'll have probems doing that. You'll need a custom webhook. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/webhook-only-processing-orders/

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Woocommerce webhooks and I'm not sure how you're integrating with Stripe. Maybe if you shed some more lights and elaborate more I might be able to weigh in on this with an actual answer rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> But does Stripe have the info of what products have been bought by customer, apart from amount paid?

Yes, it does. The [`checkout.session.completed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) event includes the Checkout Session object, which in turn includes (NB not by default) expandable [`line_items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) list.